# send message to mobile api j2me

Tags: exception, compiler-errors, java-me, illegalargumentexception

Hello everyone I'm getting this error:

```
Uncaught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port Number formatted badly 
  - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.sms.Protocol.openPrimInternal(), bci=209
  - com.sun.midp.io.j2me.sms.Protocol.openPrim(), bci=4
  - javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=47
  - javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=3
  - javax.microedition.io.Connector.open(), bci=2
  - travel.entities.SendMessage$1.run(SendMessage.java:31)
  - java.lang.Thread.run(), bci=5
```

when converting those two textfields to send them

```
public TextField tfDestination = new TextField("Destination","", 20, TextField.PHONENUMBER);
public TextField tfPort = new TextField("Port", "50001", 6, TextField.NUMERIC);
```

using this method:

```
public static void execute(final String destination, final String port, final String message) {

  Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
      MessageConnection msgConnection;
      try {
        msgConnection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open("sms://:"+port+":"+destination);
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage)msgConnection.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
        textMessage.setPayloadText(message);
        msgConnection.send(textMessage);
        msgConnection.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });

  th.start();
}
```

I'm getting the error on this line:

```
msgConnection = (MessageConnection)Connector.open("sms://:"+destination+":"+port);
```

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: anyone please have an answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Your destination should come before port number.

Try this:

```
public static void execute(final String destination, final String port, final String message) {

  Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
      MessageConnection msgConnection;
      String address = "sms://:"+destination+":"+port;
      try {
        msgConnection = (MessageConnection) Connector.open(address);
        TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) msgConnection.newMessage(MessageConnection.TEXT_MESSAGE);
        textMessage.setAddress(address);
        textMessage.setPayloadText(message);
        msgConnection.send(textMessage);
        msgConnection.close();
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  });
  th.start();
}
```

Comment: Same error :(Uncaught exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Port Number formatted badly

Comment: Try hardcoding a destination and port then. I have that exact code-snippet in one of my own MIDlets, and it's working fine for me. I'm guessing something must go wrong with the input then.

Comment: how is that my friend i didn't understand i'm just a beginner